# loop through List<double> error method mismatch

Tags: c#

error is the best overloaded method match for system.collections.generic.list has some invalid arguments also an error about converting `ienumerable<int>` to `ienumerable<double>`

```
List<double> list = new List<double>(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10000));

for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    list[i] = 10-(0.01*i);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because first parameter you pass to `Enumerable.Range` is an `int` generic parameter gets infered to be `int` as well, so `Enumerable.Range(0, 10000)` returns `IEnumerable<int>`, which is not suitable for `List<double>` constructor.

Change `0` to `0d` in your `Enumerable.Repeat` call:

```
List<double> list = new List<double>(Enumerable.Repeat(0d, 10000));
```

Or specify generic parameter when calling it:

```
List<double> list = new List<double>(Enumerable.Repeat<double>(0, 10000));
```

which will force `0` to be converted to `double`.

Comment: Nice one! I'd probably use `0.0` instead of `0d`, though.

Comment: @Heinzi No harm specifying, I would think.